# What does processType mean in process definition in activity bpmn engine?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Cosider example:

```
<process id="MyStart" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true" name="myName" processType="None">
```

What `processType="None"`? I ahve already look up activity [user guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/) but there is no information about it. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the "processType" attribute in the "process" tag, so I just checked the source of the Activiti 5.19 engine and could find no mention of it, meaning, in Activiti at least it is ignored.

However, processType is a valid BPMN 2.0 attribute for the process element and is essentially an additional piece of metadata that may be used by the engine.

In the case of Activiti, it is unused.